# Creating a shareable Google Virtual Machine with bucket permissions

Tags: virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-iam

Within our organization group we have a fairly high turnover for Google Compute Engine Virtual Machines and lots of people using them. Therefore, we are looking into creating an internal shareable VM image, mainly with Python/R set up already alongside some useful environments and some other command line tools.

Ideally, the easy VM setup would be accompanied by easy access to our group Google Cloud Storage buckets. However, there are inconsistencies in how different parts of the group access VMs. Some do it via google cloud SDK at the terminal (so authentication is done for the user). Other parts via the browser SSH button, which logs in as a different user seemingly without any permissions granted. There is also a reluctance to install the SDK on local machines.

Is there a good way to create a shareable VM image (+workflow) that allows access to buckets easily? E.g. can we grant permission to a VM image instead of a user?

Comment: Linux is an operating system that can be configured as a multiuser server. Yes, you can grant permissions to the VM via the attached service account. Those permissions will be shared among all users. Users can also authenticate using their IAM credentials to manage permissions instead of the VM's service account's permissions. There are many possibilities. As written your question is too broad. Rewrite your question into a single problem that can be answered with facts and/or citations. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I recommend creating a separate VM for each user. Isolation and security are major factors. Those individual VMs should be configured for long-term usage and not be created over and over again. Use additional testing VMs for those use cases. Google Cloud offers Cloud Shell which might fit well into your environment for one-off users as well as developers that do not require large development environments.